# No query results for model in Laravel with Dingo - how to make a RESTful response on failure?

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel, dingo-api

I'm creating an API with Laravel based on the [Dingo API](https://github.com/dingo/api).

In my routes, I have:

```
Route::api('v1', function () {
    Route::resource('object', 'My\Namespace\MyController');
});
```

And in MyController:

```
class MyController extends \Illuminate\Routing\Controller {

    use Dingo\Api\Routing\ControllerTrait;

    public function index() {
        return MyObject::all();
    }

    public function show($id) {
        return MyObject::findOrFail($id);
    }

}
```

This means that `api.domain.com/object` calls `MyController@index`, which works. Since there are no items in the database, this then outputs an empty json array `[]`.

`api.domain.com/object/123` calls `MyController@show(123)`. This is according to https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Responses. However, since there are no results in the database, I get:

```
No query results for model [My\Namespace\MyObject].
```

**I would expect this to give a nice RESTful error instead. How do I do that?**

The code of MyObject is nothing special, it's an empty class which extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.

I'm using Laravel 4.2; 5 is not supported by Dingo yet.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? 4 or 5?

Comment: @lukasgeiter sorry, forgot that. I'm using laravel 4.2, as 5 isn't supported by Dingo yet.

Comment: Do you `use` the `ControllerTrait` in your controller?

Comment: @Vohuman I do, yes, I'll add that to my question.

Comment: I'm happy to see a questioner responds so quickly. Very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to handle it yourself and add a custom error as described [here](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Errors-And-Error-Responses#custom-exception-responses). `findOrFail()` will throw a `ModelNotFoundException` so let's catch that:

```
API::error(function (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e){
    return Response::make(['error' => 'Resource not found'], 404);
});
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. So where would be the best place to put that code? This is in my own package - should I put it in the ServiceProvider?

Comment: Yes inside a ServiceProvider is the perfect place for that :)

Comment: @CamilStaps Exactly :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was a little hasty with accepting because I still have a small problem. Now, I'm getting `Call to undefined method Dingo\Api\Http\Response::make()`. What Response class are you using here exactly? Also the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` class doesn't work (same error).

Comment: That's just Laravels `Response` facade. (`Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response`). But there is an alias in the global namespace so you shouldn't even need to import it...

Comment: That works, thanks very much! (Without anything, I got `Class 'My\Namespace\Response'` not found.)

Comment: Ah I see... you also just do `\Response::make()` or `use Response;` at the top. Or as you now probably did `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response`