# How to return custom API response for "No query results for model", Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building an RESTful API in Laravel 5.2.

In my resource controllers I want to use implicit model binding to show resources. e.g.

```
public function show(User $users)
{
    return $this->respond($this->userTransformer->transform($users));
}
```

When a request is made for a resource that doesn't exist Laravel automatically returns the NotFoundHttpException

[NotFoundHttpException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZQfp.png)

I want to return my own custom response but how can I do that for a query that is done using route model binding?

Would something like this [Dingo API response answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28645259/2349608) be able to be implemented?

Or will I stick with my old code which was something like this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    if ( ! $user ) {
        return $this->respondNotFound('User does not exist');
    }

    return $this->respond($this->userTransformer->transform($users));
}
```

So I could see if a resource (user) was not found and return an appropriate response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if you can catch `ModelNotFound` instead.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException) {
        dd('model not found');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a good place would be in the `Handler.php` file under `/app/Exceptions`

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        // return your custom response
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: Should I create my own handler and overwrite that function?

Comment: Just place your response inside that `if` no need to create your own handler file

Comment: I tried putting in return 'My own response for testing'; and it is not being called. I am still getting the NotFoundHttpException in the browser

Comment: if you return something like: `response()->json(['message' => 'no resource was found'], 404);` it doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately not, neither works. I'll try something similar

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 7 and 8 you can do something like this.

In app/Exception/Handler.php class, add the render() method like below(if it doesn't exist).

Note that instead of type hinting **Exception** class you should use **Throwable** .

```
use Throwable;

public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException) {
        //For API (json)
        if (request()->wantsJson()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Record Not Found !!!'
            ], 404);
        }

        //Normal 
        return view('PATH TO YOUR ERROR PAGE'); 
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```