# Laravel Validation Request & API route POST parameter

Tags: laravel, rest, api, validation

I'm facing a little issue with Form Request Validation and how to handle it with one API route.

The resource that I need to create depends on an other resource.

(Here an EmailSettings belongs to a Tenant)

So the look of my route should be something like : /api/tenants/{id}/email_settings

And my request validation expects several fields including the tenantId :

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'email' => 'bail|required|email|unique:email_settings,email',
        'name' => 'bail|required',
        'username' => 'bail|required',
        'password' => 'bail|required'
        'imapHost' => 'bail|required',
        'imapPort' => 'bail|required',
        'imapEncryption' => 'bail|required',
        'imapValidateCert' => 'bail|required',
        'smtpHost' => 'bail|required',
        'smtpPort' => 'bail|required',
        'smtpEncryption' => 'bail|required',
        'tenantId' => 'bail|required',
    ];
}
```

And I send the request like this :

```
try {
    const response = await this.tenantForm.post('/api/tenants')
    let newTenant = helpers.getNewResourceFromResponseHeaderLocation(response)
    let tenantId = parseInt(newTenant.id);
    try {
        await this.emailSettingsForm.post('/api/tenants/' + tenantId + '/email_settings')
        this.requestAllTenants()
    } catch ({response}) {
        $('.second.modal').modal({blurring: true, closable: false}).modal('show');
    }
} catch ({response}) {
    $('.first.modal').modal({blurring: true}).modal('show');
}
```

So the tenantId is passed as a parameter and not in the request body to respect the REST convention. 
But the problem is in my Controller, when I merge the data to create the resource, the validation has already took place only on body data before the merge.

```
public function store(EmailSettingValidation $request, $tenant_id) {
    $emailSetting = $this->emailSettingService->create(
        array_merge($request->all(), compact($tenant_id))
    );
    return $this->response->created($emailSetting);
}
```

So what is the best way to handle it properly ?

- Pass the id in the body ? Seems messy
- Use Validator to validate manually ? I would prefer to keep Form Validation
- Remove the tenantId rule and check it manually ?

Any suggestions ?
Thank you

Comment: Do you have a model for your tenant table?

Comment: @TravisBritz Yes, but why is it important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I found to trigger 404 is the following :

- Remove the tenantId from EmailSettings Validation
- Add a provider to add a custom error when the exception 'ModelNotFoundException' occurs like here
  [No query results for model in Laravel with Dingo - how to make a RESTful response on failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645259/no-query-results-for-model-in-laravel-with-dingo-how-to-make-a-restful-respons)
- Try to throw this Exception with the findOrFail method if invalid ID :

  ```
  public function store(EmailSettingValidation $request, $tenant_id) {
      Tenant::findOrFail($tenant_id);
      $emailSetting = $this->emailSettingService->create(
          array_merge($request->all(), ['tenantId' => $tenant_id])
      );
      return $this->response->created($emailSetting);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

If you define your api route like this:

```php
Roue::post('tenants/{tenant}/emails_settings', 'Controller@store');
```

and modify your controller method to type-hint the model with a variable name that matches your route definition:

```php
public function store(EmailSettingValidation $request, Tenant $tenant) {}
```

then Laravel will automatically find the Tenant by ID and inject it into the controller, throwing a ModelNotFoundException (404) if it doesn't exist. That should take care of validating the id.

Authorization is another matter.

Comment: Your solution works well (if we add the middleware 'bindings' to the route) but when the Tenant doesn't exist, it returns "500 : No query results for model [App\Tenant]" and not 404 and I don't know why :/

Comment: @guillaumehanotel what version of Laravel is this?

Comment: This is version 5.5

Comment: @guillaumehanotel does your `web` middleware group include the `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,`?

Comment: Yes but I defined my routes in the api.php so the web group doesn't apply

Comment: Does the `api` group include `'bindings'`? It should by default

Comment: You've renamed the `{id}` route parameter to `{tenant}` as well, correct?

Comment: Yes it is, but bindings doesn't work until I specify explicitly in the routes. But I use the Dingo package to do my API so maybe that's why.    And yes {tenant}

Comment: I repeat your solution works, but when i deliberately set a false Id, it's error 500 and not 404

Comment: Yeah I understood that part, but 500 isn't exactly the desired result. I think use of the Dingo package explains it though!

Answer (score 0):

Travis Britz and Guillaumehanotel each have half of your answer, but you're still missing a detail.

From Travis Britz- Yes, include the tenant_id on the URI so it gets injected into the controller.
From Guillaumehanotel- Also used the Eloquent [findOrFail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) in that Id in your Controller (or whatever class the Controller is leveraging to do this, like a Repository or Service class).

The last piece you're missing though is handling the error.  You can do this in the Controller if you like, but I generally like making it a rule for my entire system that the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` Exceptions that come out of `findOrFail()` should always result in a 404.

Go to `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`.  I'm pretty sure Laravel auto-generates a meat and potatoes version of this file for you, but if you don't already have one, it should look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

/**
 * Class Handler
 * @package App\Exceptions
 */
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * For our API, we need to override the call
     * to the parent.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Exception $e
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $error)
    {
        $exception = [
            'title' => 'Internal Error',
            'message' => $error->getMessage();
        ];
        $statusCode = 500;
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type', 'application/json'
        ];

        return response()->json($exception, $statusCode, $headers, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
}
```

Laravel basically has a system-wide `try/catch` that sends all errors through here first.  That's how errors get rendered into something the browser can actually interpret when you're in debug-mode, rather than just kill the process outright.  This also gives you the opportunity to apply a few special rules.

So all you need to do is tell `Handler::render()` to change the default error code that occurs when it sees the type of error that can only come from `findOrFail()`.  (This kind of thing is why it's always good to make your own 'named exceptions', even if they do absolutely nothing except inherit the base `\Exception` class.)

Just add this just before `render()` returns anything:

```
if ($error instanceof Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException) {
    $statusCode = 404;
}
```

Comment: This is already the default behavior of Laravel. The reason for the 500 status code is an external library they're using (dingo/api) that has its own exception handling.